# Custom Yeoman generator - how do I specify which package manager to use?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I made a custom Yeoman generator using yeoman-generator v 5.8.0, and everything seems to be working fine except that I get an error in the console:

`Error detecting the package manager. Falling back to npm.`

Which in the end is also fine, it still works, but I'd like it to not report an error.

The only way I can find to specify the package manager to use is either calling one of the specific package manager install functions explicitly, i.e.

```
this.npmInstall()
```

or by calling the general `installDependencies` function with options, i.e.

```
this.installDependencies({
  npm: true,
  yarn: false,
  bower: false
})
```

However, since version 5.0.0 all of the `install` functions are deprecated.

https://yeoman.github.io/generator/actions_install.html

https://github.com/yeoman/generator/releases/tag/v5.0.0

So how do I specify the package manager to use so I won't get that error message?

Answer (score 2):

if you're still looking for an answer, based on [this](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/1294#issuecomment-841668595), you can add
`this.env.options.nodePackageManager = "yarn";` inside the generator. I can confirm it worked for on Yeoman v^5.